# Promise fails to catch

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, promise

I'm trying to understand error catching in promises and I'm not getting something.  I've read up on it and from everything I've seen it should be working so I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I have a sample method that for now I'm just throwing an error (to simulate when it may actually throw an error later).  That method looks like this:

```
DeleteProject(id: string, customerId: string): Promise<void> {
    throw new Error('test error');
}
```

I'm then calling this in my code like this:

```
projectService.DeleteProject(state.FocusedProject.ID, state.FocusedProject.CustomerID)
    .then(() => {
        ...stuff when it works...
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('caught you');
        HandleError(error, 'Delete Project');
    });
```

When this method does not throw an error the code in the `then` block gets called and all works fine.  However, when I throw the error it gives me an unhandled execution error and the `catch` block is never called.

From everything I've read, throwing an error inside of that function should automatically be caught and return the rejected promise right?  If so then when is it not being caught?

I'm sure I'm missing something here but I can't see what it is.  I basically want the `catch` block to say 'if anything goes wrong in the method I called then do this'.

Comment: `DeleteProject` isn't async, so the error doesn't become a rejected promise, it's a _synchronous_ error. Make the function async, or try e.g. `return Promise.reject('test error')`.

Comment: Right; the exception is thrown, there's no Promise constructed, so the `.catch()` block is irrelevant.

Comment: I see, I guess that makes sense.  So is there a way to catch that error as well?

Comment: @sfaust: *"So is there a way to catch that error as well?"* - Wrap the call to `DeleteProject()` in a `try/catch`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will work with that.

Comment: FWIW, unless there's real value in handling the error synchronously, it might be better to use the `return Promise.reject(new Error(...))` style here instead. It is atypical to require function caller to handle both styles of error (synchronous and asynchronous), and presumably it is possible for DeleteProject to return an error asynchronously if it communicates with the server. This would mean that callers only have one error channel to handle regardless of whether the error is synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: Ok, I think I do need to handle both though.  I have a client that is generated from a swagger definition using NSwag.  The client has the async errors that can come up (bad request, server error, etc.) but it also has some handling that throws a sync error if something wrong is submitted (so that it doesn't try to submit to the server).  Generally the debugging phase would catch the second type but I still think it would be good to catch those errors and give the user an error notification rather than an app failure no matter how the error ocurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments, DeleteProject is marked as returning a `Promise<void>` but it is not marked `async`. Like all non-`async` functions, it can throw errors, which are then caught as part of a `try`/`catch` block instead of a call to `Promise.then` or `Promise.catch`. These are two separate error channels that have to be handled separately.

Promise machinery will convert errors thrown with `throw` into rejected Promises, but only in these situations:

1. In a [`new Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#parameters)
2. In a function passed to [`Promise.then` or `Promise.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value)
3. In an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value)

Unless there's real value in handling the error synchronously, it might be better to use the `return Promise.reject(new Error(...))` style here instead of `throw new Error(...)`. It is atypical to require function caller to handle both styles of error (synchronous and asynchronous), and presumably it is possible for DeleteProject to return an error asynchronously if it communicates with the server. This would mean that callers only have one error channel to handle regardless of whether the error is synchronous or asynchronous.

In a follow-up comment from the OP ([sfaust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533068/sfaust)), they suggest that they will need to handle both types (asynchronous from the server, and synchronous from invalid input). Distinguishing between development-time error and runtime errors is a rational reason, but if so it may be very important to document the fact that the function (DeleteProject here) can issue both types of error. Remember, though, that even when errors can be detected or caught synchronously, it's still up to you what kind of external API you provide to callers of your function: For manually-written promise-returning functions (i.e. without `async`), it may still be more predictable to send all errors through a rejected promise, even if it means wrapping the function in a `try`/`catch` block and using a particular subclass of Error to indicate invalid calls to the function.